# How to add ActionListeners to buttons within an ArrayList?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, arraylist, actionlistener

I'm working on a project in which a parsing program read data from an input file, tokenizes it, then builds a GUI out of it. In this case it's a calculator GUI. I'm trying to write the code for the calculator operations now and I'm having trouble adding ActionListeners to the buttons of the calculator. They are stored in an ArrayList and when I try using the addActionListener() function I receive the following error:

[ActionListener error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9amK.png)

Below is my code for the builder file:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GUIBuilder implements ActionListener {
    //Declare variables
    boolean[] function = new boolean[4];
    double[] temp = {0, 0};
    static JFrame outputFrame;  //Declare GUI window frame
    static JPanel panel1, panel2, panel3, panel4;  //Declare GUI panel variables
    static Container container;  //Declare GUI container variable
    static JTextField textField;  //Declare GUI text field variable
    static ArrayList<JButton> button;
    static ArrayList<JLabel> label;
    static ArrayList<JRadioButton> radio;
    static GUIParser guiParser;  //Create instance of GUIParser 

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    //Instantiates a GUIParser object
    guiParser = new GUIParser();

    //Instantiates ArrayList objects
    button = new ArrayList<>();
    label = new ArrayList<>();      
    radio = new ArrayList<>();

    //Instantiates a GUIBuilder object that invokes frameConstructor() method
    GUIBuilder guiBuilder = new GUIBuilder();
    guiBuilder.frameConstructor();  
    }

    public void frameConstructor() {

    //Instantiates a JFrame object
    outputFrame = new JFrame();

    //Sets window size
    outputFrame.setSize(this.guiParser.getWindowWidth(),this.guiParser.getWindowHeight());  //Sets size of outputFrame to the return value of getWindowWidth method

    //Sets window name
    outputFrame.setTitle(this.guiParser.getWindowName());  //Sets title of window to return value of getWindowName method
    outputFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  //Sets the default close operation to exit

    container = outputFrame.getContentPane();
    if (this.guiParser.getWindowLayout() == 0) { //If return value of getWindowLayout is 0, use flow layout
            container.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    } else { //If return value is other than 0, use grid layout
            if (this.guiParser.getHorizontalSpace() != 0 && this.guiParser.getVerticalSpace() != 0) {  //If return values of getHorizontalSpace and getVerticalSpace are zero, create Grid layout with these dimensions
        container.setLayout(new GridLayout
        (this.guiParser.getNumRows(),this.guiParser.getNumColumns(),
        this.guiParser.getHorizontalSpace(),this.guiParser.getVerticalSpace()));
            } else {  //Otherwise create a Grid layout with these dimensions
                container.setLayout(new GridLayout
        (this.guiParser.getNumRows(),this.guiParser.getNumColumns()));
            }
    }

    //Instantiates new JPanel objects
    panel1 = new JPanel();
    panel2 = new JPanel();
    panel3 = new JPanel();
    panel4 = new JPanel();
    if (this.guiParser.getPanelLayout() == 0) { //If return value of getPanelLayout is zero, use flow layout
            panel1.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            panel2.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            panel3.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        } else { //Otherwise use grid layout, set dimensions according to input values
            if (this.guiParser.getHorizontalSpace() != 0 && this.guiParser.getVerticalSpace() != 0) {
        panel1.setLayout(new GridLayout
                    (this.guiParser.getNumRows(),this.guiParser.getNumColumns(),
                        this.guiParser.getHorizontalSpace(),this.guiParser.getVerticalSpace()));
        panel2.setLayout(new GridLayout
                    (this.guiParser.getNumRows(),this.guiParser.getNumColumns(),
            this.guiParser.getHorizontalSpace(),this.guiParser.getVerticalSpace()));
        panel3.setLayout(new GridLayout
                    (this.guiParser.getNumRows(),this.guiParser.getNumColumns(),
            this.guiParser.getHorizontalSpace(),this.guiParser.getVerticalSpace()));
        panel4.setLayout(new GridLayout
                    (this.guiParser.getNumRows(),this.guiParser.getNumColumns(),
            this.guiParser.getHorizontalSpace(),this.guiParser.getVerticalSpace()));
            } else {
        panel1.setLayout(new GridLayout
                    (this.guiParser.getNumRows(),this.guiParser.getNumColumns()));
        panel2.setLayout(new GridLayout
                    (this.guiParser.getNumRows(),this.guiParser.getNumColumns()));
        panel3.setLayout(new GridLayout
                    (this.guiParser.getNumRows(),this.guiParser.getNumColumns()));
        panel4.setLayout(new GridLayout
                    (this.guiParser.getNumRows(),this.guiParser.getNumColumns()));
            }
    }

    //Instantiates a JTextField object and sets text field width with the return value of getTextWidth()   
    textField = new JTextField("", this.guiParser.getTextWidth());
    container.add(textField);  //Add the text field to the Jframe container
    panel1.add(textField);  //Add the text field to panel 1

    //Walk through the buttonList array and add buttons to the container and panel 2
    int i = 0;
    Iterator<String> iterator = this.guiParser.getButtonList().iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            button.add(new JButton(iterator.next()));
            container.add(button.get(i));
            panel2.add(button.get(i));
            button.addActionListener(this);
            i++;
    }

    //Walk through the radioList array and add radio buttons to the container and panel 3
    i = 0;
    iterator = this.guiParser.getRadioList().iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            radio.add(new JRadioButton(iterator.next()));
            container.add(radio.get(i));
            panel3.add(radio.get(i));
            i++;
    }

    //Walk through the labelList array and add labels to the container and panel 4
    i = 0;
    iterator = this.guiParser.getLabelList().iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            label.add(new JLabel(iterator.next()));
            container.add(label.get(i));
            panel4.add(label.get(i));
            i++;
    }

        //Add each panel to the output frame and set its visibility
    outputFrame.add(panel1);
    outputFrame.add(panel2);
    outputFrame.add(panel3);
    outputFrame.setVisible(true);
        for(i = 0; i < 16; i++){

        }
    }

    public void clear(){
        try{
            textField.setText("");
            for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
                function[i] = false;
            }
            for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
                temp[i] = 0;
            }
        } catch(NullPointerException e){

        }
    }


    public void calcResult(){
        double result = 0;
        temp[1] = Double.parseDouble(textField.getText());
        String temp0 = Double.toString(temp[0]);
        String temp1 = Double.toString(temp[1]);
        try{
            if(temp0.contains("-")){
                String[] temp00 = temp0.split("-", 2);
                temp[0] = (Double.parseDouble(temp00[1]) * -1);
            }
            if(temp1.contains("-")){
                String[] temp11 = temp1.split("-", 2);
                temp[1] = (Double.parseDouble(temp11[1]) * -1);
            }
        } catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){

        }
        try{
            if(function[2] == true){
                result = temp[0] * temp[1];
            } else if(function[3] == true){
                result = temp[0] / temp[1];
            } else if(function[0] == true){
                result = temp[0] + temp[1];
            } else if(function[1] == true){
                result = temp[0] - temp[1];
            }
            textField.setText(Double.toString(result));
            for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
                function[i] = false;
            }
        } catch(NumberFormatException e){

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent ae) {
        if(ae.getSource() == button.get(0)){
            textField.setText("1");
        }
        if(ae.getSource() == button.get(1)){
            textField.setText(textField.getText().concat("2"));
        }
        if(ae.getSource() == button.get(2)){
            textField.setText(textField.getText().concat("3"));
        }
        if(ae.getSource() == button.get(3)){
            textField.setText(textField.getText().concat("4"));
        }
        if(ae.getSource() == button.get(4)){
            textField.setText(textField.getText().concat(""));
        }
        if(ae.getSource() == button.get(5)){
            textField.setText(textField.getText().concat("1"));
        }
        if(ae.getSource() == button.get(6)){
            textField.setText(textField.getText().concat("1"));
        }
        if(ae.getSource() == button.get(7)){
            textField.setText(textField.getText().concat("1"));
        }
        if(ae.getSource() == button.get(8)){
            textField.setText(textField.getText().concat("1"));
        }
        if(ae.getSource() == button.get(9)){
            textField.setText(textField.getText().concat("1"));
        }
        if(ae.getSource() == button.get(10)){
            textField.setText(textField.getText().concat("1"));
        }
        if(ae.getSource() == button.get(11)){
            textField.setText(textField.getText().concat("1"));
        }
        if(ae.getSource() == button.get(12)){
            textField.setText(textField.getText().concat("1"));
        }
        if(ae.getSource() == button.get(13)){
            textField.setText(textField.getText().concat("1"));
        }
        if(ae.getSource() == button.get(14)){
            textField.setText(textField.getText().concat("1"));
        }
        if(ae.getSource() == button.get(15)){
            textField.setText(textField.getText().concat("1"));
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: as you may have observed naming is important. Always use propernameming! In our case using a sngular name for a collection was confusing, supported the error and made the debugging harder!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `button.addActionListener(this);` should be `button.get(i).addActionListener(this);`.

That being said, you should keep a reference to the button that you create in each iteration instead of retrieving it from the ArrayList every time you subsequently modify it in that loop:

```
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        JButton newButton = new JButton(iterator.next());
        button.add(newButton);
        container.add(newButton);
        panel2.add(newButton);
        newButton.addActionListener(this);
}
```

Comment: You're the man. Worked swimmingly. I don't know what i was thinking!!

Answer (score 3):

Your button variable is an ArrayList, and so this:

```
button.addActionListener(this);
```

makes no sense, since it doesn't make sense to add an ActionListener to an ArrayList. You want to add the ActionListener to the JButton element **held by** the ArrayList. So...

```
button.get(i).addActionListener(this);
```

Other issues:

- Your code is over-using the static modifier, and this will make it very inflexible and can even increase the risk for future bugs. Java is an object-oriented language, and is best used if you create your apps in an OOP way.
- You never want to do: `catch(NullPointerException e){`. If your code throws an NPE, then it's broken code and needs to be fixed.